# auto fill for input fieldas is not considering the label

Tags: html, browser

I have the following input lines in a registration form

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="email">Email:</label>

    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="institute">Institute:</label>

    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="institute" name="institute" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="password">Password:</label>

    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

but Chrome always auto fills the email in the institute field when I open this form? I thought the browser is using the labels for auto fill? Does anybody know how I can make sure that Chrome puts the email in the correct field?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 1):

You did not add the email type for the email input. The Auto-Fill searches for email field but does not find it and then put the email in the another field. For email inputs, you need to specify the type of the input fields to `email`.

Change following:

```
<input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
```

With:

```
<input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" value="">
```

Comment: hi Maihan. Good point, but changing this did not solve the problem? thanks anyway for pointing this out

Comment: @carl Thanks for feedback. Clear your history (cache, cookies) as the Chrome have already the previous instructions, how to fill the form. The above works fine for me. Just tested now.

Comment: hm even after deleting all cookies (I think in Chrome the history option to delete is "auto fill from data") it does not work